# Socket IO Emit server blocking

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have node server running on ec2 instance. When user performs any action, I am emitting an event. Does this socket emit blocks server I/O operation?

eg - I have 10000 users connected at 1 moment, and on one action I have to emit a message to all connected users, will this emit block my network I/O for other operations?

Comment: Can you show the code, or a minimal representation of what you're talking about? You may want to wrap this up in some kind of Promise dispatcher like `Promise.each` or `Promise.all` to avoid jamming your process on a large number of calls.

Comment: I am just emitting something like this io.emit(emitMatchLobbyID, { data: 'update' }); But I have around 10,000 users connected to system who are listening to this emit. So does it block my other operation on server?

Comment: How long does 10,000 calls take? As Sergey says, Node.js is single threaded, so unless you break that up into smaller chunks you're going to jam your Node process.

Comment: So each call was taking 1-2 seconds.

Comment: But is not node asynchronous? It will accept other request and when callback is done for each, it will return response.

Comment: It's asynchronous, but that doesn't mean that it's going to make code that jams up the main event loop run seamlessly. It's your responsibility to break up any long operations into smaller chunks. If it takes 1000ms to do those calls, you should do 100 groups of 100, that blocks for 10ms or maybe 50 groups of 200 at 20ms each. Whatever it takes to break up your processing.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Nodejs single threaded.